# Error when installing pods (cocoapods)

Tags: cocoapods

I was having trouble using cocoa pods in a project so i decided to uninstall and reinstall. Now its broke. Iv completely removed all cocoa pods from my system and reinstalled. (including removing the cocoa pods directory)

```
gem install cocoapods
pod setup
```

Seems to have worked

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo

CocoaPods 1.2.0.beta.1 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.2.0.beta.1

Setup completed
```

Now after i pod install:

```
pod install --verbose
  Preparing
Unknown option: -C
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
Unknown option: -C
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]

Setting up CocoaPods master repo
  $ /usr/local/bin/git remote set-url origin
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
  $ /usr/local/bin/git checkout master
  Already on 'master'
Unknown option: -C
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`.
(The `master` repo is not a git repo.)
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:35:in `rescue in find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:38:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:814:in `block in sources'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:813:in `map'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:813:in `sources'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:143:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:110:in `install!'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in `run'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Nic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I actually had cocoa pods working fine before i uninstalled, but now this happens every time! 
My pod file:

```
target 'Project' do

  pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.0'

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by updating git. Also have to link it with brew if it doesn't update properly